# LibGit2Sharp - Getting different dates for different repsoitories

Tags: git, tfs, libgit2sharp

I am using Lib2GitSharp to show a history of all commits in various repositories. All my remotes are on the same TFS server (I am using Git for TFS) and were set up same. However, for some of the repositories, I get the Author.When time as UTC and for others I get it as time in local time zone. Any ideas??

My code is a below

```
foreach (LibGit2Sharp.Commit gitCommit in remote.Commits.Where(s => s.IsMergeCommit() == false).OrderByDescending(s => s.Author.When).Take(numberOfCommits))
        {
            if (!gitCommit.IsMergeCommit())
            {
                commits.Add(new PipelineMonitor.Data.Contract.Commit
                {
                    DateCommitted = gitCommit.Author.When.DateTime,
                    Comment = gitCommit.MessageShort,
                    Id = gitCommit.Id.ToString(),
                    Owner = gitCommit.Author.Name,
                    WorkItemId = GetWorkItemId(gitCommit)
                });
            }
        }
```

Comment: `When` is a DateTimeOffset. Why do you extract the local DateTime out of it?

Comment: It's a requirement of a local application I am writing. The issue is that we get different time zones for the field from different repositories

Comment: A `DateTimeOffset` will store UTC time alongside the offset to the UTC from the timezone it's been created. If you can't expose a `DateTimeOffset`, I'd suggest you rather return `When.UtcDateTime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the time type "UtcDateTime"  for "When" to get UTC time for all commits:

```
DateCommitted = gitCommit.Author.When.UtcDateTime,
```

Or use "LocalDateTime" to get local time for all commits if you want:

```
DateCommitted = gitCommit.Author.When.LocalDateTime,
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Yes, I was using When.DateTime. Changing to UtcDatetime did the trick for me.